# Persist change inside for loop R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a function that takes a data.table and perform several calculations based on it. Later, append to that particular data.table the newly created rows (based on this calculations). Inside that loop, i need in the second iteration to work on the data.table previously modified. Is that possible?

I realize that the `<<-` operator could help maybe, but I read several times it's unsafe.

Example:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  dosomething[[i]] <- dataTable[search %in% here]
  #
  #several calculations over dosomething object
  #...
  dataTable <- rbind(dataTable, dosomething)
}
```

Here I need to start the second iteration, but `dataTable` has changed. How do I repeat the same sequence of calculations but this time with the new version of `dataTable`?

Thanks.

Comment: `for` loops don't have their own scoped environments like functions do, so there is no need for `<<-`. It's difficult to help without a reproducible example - could you share a little bit of illustrative data and some placeholders for calculations so we can actually demonstrate a working solution on a tangible problem?

Comment: In your code, the 2nd, 3rd, etc iterations work on the modified data table. I don't understand the question, have you tried to run that code in a small dt?